# Unable to Call jasper report from Jar file

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using the following code to call a jasper report

```
  String reportSource = "/report.jrxml";


            InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(reportSource);
            JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JasperCompileManager.compileReport(is);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, conn);
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
```

Code is working fine when i run it in netbeans ide. but when i build the application and create the jar and run it , i am not getting report popup.

Comment: The `.jrxml` should have already been compiled.  Then all you need to do is load the resulting `.jasper` file and fill it...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am using this but report still not showing                                                                    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(getClass().getResource("report.jasper").getPath(), null, conn);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(print);

Comment: i am getting FileNotFound Exception

Comment: Post the full stack trace and highlight the location in your code the exception is been triggered

Comment: You see this `getClass().getResource("report.jasper").getPath()` <--- What do I say about `.getPath()`?

Comment: .getPath() is stored in path variable and i am printing it above. both when i run project in netbeans and jar. but now i am not getting the path. i am getting the stream using getResourceAsStream()

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert the results of `getClass().getResource("report.jrxml")` to a `String`, instead, you want to use `getClass().getResourceAsStream("report.jrxml")` and pass this into `JasperCompileManager.compileReport(InputStream)`

```
try (InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("report.jrxml")) {
    JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(is);
}
```

Having said all that, you should not be deploying or compiling your `.jrxml` files at runtime.

As part of your build process, you should be compiling the `.jrxml` files into `.japser` files and simply loading and filling them at runtime.

```
try (InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("report.jrxml")) {
    JasperReport report = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(is);
}
```

This way you save yourself the hassle of wasting runtime compiling the report each time...

ps, you can also use...

```
JasperReport report = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(getClass().getResource("report.jrxml"));
```

Comment: I am using this but report still not showing when i run the jar file                                                                    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("report.jrxml");
        JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(is);
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, null, conn); 
        JasperViewer.viewReport(print);

Comment: Does it throw an `Exception`?  Have you added debug statements in to see where the code gets to??

Comment: Yes , i am getting FileNotFound Exception

Comment: From which call?  From one of the Jasper calls or from within code?

Comment: From one of jasper calls

Comment: And FileNotFoundException occures only when i run the jar file.

Comment: Post the full stack trace - can't help you without.  The above code is (just about) what we use in production every day

Comment: I am getting problem when running jar. how can i see the log then ?

Comment: You could run the jar from the command line.  You could use something like log4j and log the content to a file

Comment: Please Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25844357/calling-jasperreport-from-jar

Comment: Why duplicate it?  You can't provide the information we need to fix it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61253/discussion-between-usman-riaz-and-madprogrammer).